# Appwidgetmanager.updateAppwidget() not doing anything

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I'm creating an app widget that queries data from a database, and uses a content observer to update a label once this data changes. The problem is that when the widget is created, I update the label to the correct value. When the data changes, the content observer correctly registers this, but I can't get the widget to update. The code looks like this:

```
//called after the configuration activity is done
public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
         int appWidgetId){
    m_appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    m_account = prefs.getString("account" + appWidgetId, "unknown");
    m_label = prefs.getString("label" + appWidgetId, "unknown");
    m_context = context;
    if (!m_accounts.contains(m_account)){
        m_accounts.add(m_account);
        m_context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(GmailContract.Labels.getLabelsUri(m_account), true,new MyContentObserver(new Handler()));
    }
    updateViews();

}
```

In the ContentObserver, I only overwrite the following function:

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        GmailUnreadCounterActivity.updateViews();
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }
```

the updateViews function looks like this (when called from updateAppWidget, it works perfectly, when called from the contentobserver, the widget isn't updated, despite the value changing)

```
public static void updateViews(){
    System.out.println("Number of widgets:" + m_appWidgetIds.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < m_appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        SharedPreferences prefs = m_context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        m_account = prefs.getString("account" + m_appWidgetIds[i], "unknown");
        m_label = prefs.getString("label" + m_appWidgetIds[i], "unknown");
        Cursor c = m_context.getContentResolver().query(GmailContract.Labels.getLabelsUri(m_account),null,null,null,null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(GmailContract.Labels.CANONICAL_NAME)).equals(m_label)){
                String line = String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS)));
                remoteViews = new RemoteViews(m_context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.unread_count,
                        line);
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(m_context).updateAppWidget(m_appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you get m_appWidgetIds?

Why do you want to keep it in a for loop and update all the instances. Instead of that use

```
updateAppWidget (ComponentName provider, RemoteViews views)
```

This will update all the instances of widget.

Use the following code to get the ComponentName
ComponentName provider = new ComponentName(context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class);

Comment: Hello, what is the purpose of  int[] appWidgetIds parameter being passed to onUpdate?

Comment: Quoting from android doc - "The appWidgetIds for which an update is needed. Note that this may be all of the AppWidget instances for this provider, or just a subset of them"